# Disable Nouveau Kernel Driver on Ubuntu 16.04.02

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I have tried all solutions on various forum. Currently, I'm at my wits end to disable the Nouveau driver and install Nvidia drivers. I have tried purging/removing previous Nvidia, blacklist files etc. but I am unable to disable nouveau.

Out put of the `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12`

```
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K620] [10de:13bb] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM107GL [Quadro K620] [103c:1098]
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f3080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau

02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fbc] (rev a1)
```

I have also blacklisted nouveau. I have tried installing Nvidia drivers via the deb package and well as downloading from the Nvidia drivers website. I have also updated the intramfs to be pruned by noveau.

Details of my Ubuntu Distribution

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

PS - Mu ultimate goal is to install CUDA drivers and toolkit.

Comment: Did you try adding the NVidia drivers via the software updater/settings button/Additional Drivers tab (and the other software tabs for proprietary software repositories)?

Comment: Hi @ubfan1 I don't have access to the GUI on this machine. It's an Ubuntu LXC.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the restricted repositories enabled.
they are in /etc/apt/sources.list, and probably commented out with a #.  Delete the # at the beginning of the line.  You may have a few like:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
```

Then update your package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The nvidia 375 pacakges are the ones which are the latest available in the standard repositories, but 381 is available if you want to try -- it fixes some sleep induced artifacts, but is not as well tested.

My setup is a quadro 1000M, and the nvidia 375 packages I have are:

nvidia-375
nvidia-375-dev
nvidia-modprobe
nvidia-opencl-icd-375
nvidia-prime
nvidia-settings

Clean out all the previous nvidia package you installed, and check that there are no blacklist lines for nvidia in any file in /etc/modprobe.d
Install all the above with:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375 nvidia-375-dev nvidia-modprobe nvidia-opencl-icd-375 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
```

Reboot and see if the nvidia driver is being used:

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

---

You should have in /etc/modprobe.d two files, nvidia-375_hybrid.conf and nvidia-375_hybrid.conf which have a lines which blacklist the nouveau driver and remove any alias.  Check that no nouveau is in /etc/modules and that there is nothing in /etc/rc.local that loads nouveau.  Finally, check the dmesg output, no nouveau should be seen:

```
dmesg |grep nouveau
```

The dmesg output for nvidia should look something like:

```
$ dmesg |fgrep -i nvidia
[    1.145050] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.150438] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.154278] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    1.154407] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 244
[    1.154417] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.39  Tue Jan 31 20:47:00 PST 2017 (using threaded interrupts)
[    1.155859] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  375.39  Tue Jan 31 19:41:48 PST 2017
[    1.156840] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[   14.454118] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 240
[   35.821752] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-821d0db5-a56d-9fdf-72cc-d0eab575873a) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
```

Finally, lsmod should contain several nvidia modules and no nouveau.

---

With the nvidia driver installed, you should be able to install the Intel cuda .deb package.  with `dpkg -i`

Then using apt-get install the cuda and cuda-toolkit, those should bring in many other cuda packages.

Read the Intel instructions, adding the CUDA location to your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Copy the samples from the cuda install directory to your home or any place you have write permission, so you can run the make to build the samples. Also, I assume you have your g++ installed, and maybe build-essential  The gcc should be present by default, and 16.04 has the right versions (5) for the compilers.

Comment: I have tried the entire process but I am still unable to disable nouveau drivers.